# FacebookAds\Exception\Exception, Code: 35: LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to graph.facebook.com:443

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, laradock, libressl

Seemingly out of the blue (i.e. I haven't edited code recently), I've started receiving a lot of these error messages in my cron jobs in the past couple days:

`FacebookAds\Exception\Exception, Code: 35: LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to graph.facebook.com:443`

As a test, I was able to SSH into my server and run this without problem: `curl -vvv https://www.facebook.com`

Also, the cron job that runs every 5 minutes and often causes this error doesn't *always* cause this error. And in the few times I've manually dispatched the job, I haven't seen the error.

What does this mean, what suddenly caused my cron job to often throw this error, and how can I fix it?

<sub>P.S. These seem to be related questions but none seem to have answers about LibreSSL and Facebook:</sub>

- <sub>[Laravel 5.7 OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to graph.facebook.com:443](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54920422/laravel-5-7-openssl-ssl-connect-ssl-error-syscall-in-connection-to-graph-facebo)</sub>
- <sub>[Facebook PHP SDK: Unknown SSL protocol error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39466539/facebook-php-sdk-unknown-ssl-protocol-error)</sub>
- <sub>[SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to github.com:443](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48987512/ssl-connect-ssl-error-syscall-in-connection-to-github-com443)</sub>
- <sub>[fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/xxx': LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to github.com:443](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52732686/fatal-unable-to-access-https-github-com-xxx-libressl-ssl-connect-ssl-erro?noredirect=1&lq=1)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know the root cause, but I ran `service docker restart` and haven't noticed the error since.

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/52740968/470749 for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar error message while installing ruby gems.
Upgrading the OS to Mojave 10.14.5, solved the problem for me.